# Setting modifiers for dynamically created controls

Tags: vb.net, winforms, access-modifiers

I have been creating some `controls` during runtime like below:

```
pnl1.Controls.Add(New TextBox() With _
{
    .Name = "ItemName", _
    .Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left + AnchorStyles.Right _
}
```

And I tried to set its modifier as `Public`. Unfortunately all of my attempts got failed.
My question is: Can we set modifers for dynamically created controls?

If not, then how could I access those `controls` in other `forms`? (**Ex:** `Form1` having dynamically created control `ctrl1`, `Form2` which is present inside of the `MDI container` of `Form1`).

How can I access `ctrl1` from `Form2`? (without setting `public` modifier for `ctrl1` in `form1` we could not access it from `Form2` like this `me.parentform.ctrl1`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When not dinamically, the Visual Studio sets by default the controls as `Friend With Events`, in Vb.NET, declaring them before adding to the form. You can do the same, declare a Public `List(Of Control)` (for example) and adding your controls there when you create them dinamically.

Or even better, a `Dictionary(Of String, Control)` to access the controls by its name.

Or you can get them from the form. Using `Form1.Controls` you can access to all the controls in the form. If your control is inside another control, you need to reach the controls inside that control, for example:

```
Dim btn As Label = Ctype(Form1.Controls("GroupBox1").Controls("Label1"), Label)
```

Comment: +1 Nice Solution. I will try this out and let you know if this works.

Comment: Oops sorry, forget to accept it as my answer. I have been using your idea. You suggested me to use a public List(Of Control), But i slightly modified it. what i done was during runtime i'll add my controls to a panel which is having modifier as public. Any way thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing, that the access modifiers are there to describe the form's class during compile-time, not during runtime. Access modifiers are not a security mechanism!

For example add 3 `TextBox`es to a form. Give them the access modifier `Private`, now create an instance of your form and run the following code:

```
Dim form as Form1

For Each c As Control In form.Controls
    MessageBox.Show(c.Name)
```

You will get 3 `MessageBox`es, telling you the names of the 3 `TextBox`es, even if their access modifiers are `Private`. The difference to `Public` is that you cannot write code like this:

```
MessageBox.Show(form.TextBox1.Name)
```

You cannot access private *members* of a class this way. However, *members* are available at compile time. They declare together with the class. In this case they simplify the access to the `Control`.

Adding controls to the form during runtime will **not** create a new member in the class! It can't, because your class would have to be modified, recompiled, reinstanciated, and so on.

**Conclusion**:

1. Declaring your member `Private` does not prevent objects to access the controls they 
   encapsulate.
2. Creating controls at runtime does not affect the class.
3. You are propably looking for a design pattern like [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) or [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).